# WebAPI 2.0 Multiple Get on single controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to implement a simple WebAPI 2.0 controller to get and retrieve users from a central table.

Looking at implementing :

```
GetUserByName(string userName)
GetUserByID(int userId)
GetUserByEmail(string email)
```

Using Routing  I have been able to get the api to work with GetById and GetByName. I have also added a route prefix to the controller level

The code looks like this so far, There isn't very much being done in the API controller at the moment I just wish to test that the correct methods are being hit.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        return new List<User>();
    }

    // GET: api/Users/5
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public User Get(int id)
    {
        return new User();
    }

    [Route("{id}/PasswordHash")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string PasswordHash(int id)
    {
       return "test";
    }

    [Route(Name = "/{userName:alpha}")]
    public User GetByName(string userName)
    {
        return new User();
    }

    [Route(Name = "/GetByEmail/{email}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public User GetByEmail(string email)
    {
        return new User()
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public string Post([FromBody]User value)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Once I add in the get by email it doesn't seem to work, I've tried giving the method it's own custom routing but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the name of the routes not the routes themselves, and since both methods have the same signature with one string variable you get the problem, so change your code to be :

```
[Route("/{userName:alpha}")]
    public User GetByName(string userName)
    {
        return new User();
    }

    [Route("/GetByEmail/{email}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public User GetByEmail(string email)
    {
        return new User()
    }
```

hope this helps.